# Swift Video Feed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, video

I am new to swift development (and coding in general) and am trying to develop a table view controller that will display videos and play when the video is fully displayed.  I'm able to play the video but I really want to be able to load all videos and pause those that are not completely visible instead of reloading the video on scroll.

At this point, I have a table view class with a method that plays a video and am checking visible cells in scrollViewDidScroll.  Within the scrollViewDidScroll I have a series of if statements that I implemented to react to the number of visible cells.

TableViewCell.swift:

```
@IBOutlet weak var movieView:UIView!
var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!
var videoURL:NSURL!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    //initialize movie player
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)  
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

//Action to load video
func displayVideo() {
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.Fill
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
    moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0
    moviePlayer.view.frame = movieView.bounds
    moviePlayer.view.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(movieView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(movieView.bounds))
    movieView.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    moviePlayer.play()
}
```

TableViewController.swift:

```
var objects = [[String: String]]()
var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


//Number of table view sections
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}


//Number of table view rows
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.objects.count
}


override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {


    let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows

    if indexPaths?.count == 1 {

        let cell1:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![0] as NSIndexPath) as! TableViewCell

        var cellRect : CGRect = self.tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![0])
        cellRect = self.tableView.superview!.convertRect(cellRect, fromView: self.tableView)

        if self.tableView.frame.contains(cellRect) {
            if cell1.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing {
                print("keep playing")
            }else{
                cell1.videoURL = NSURL(string: self.objects[indexPaths![0].row]["storyLink"]!)!
                cell1.displayVideo()
            }
        }

    }else if indexPaths?.count == 2 {


        let cell1:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![0] as NSIndexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let cell2:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![1] as NSIndexPath) as! TableViewCell


        var cellRect1 : CGRect = self.tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![0])
        cellRect1 = self.tableView.superview!.convertRect(cellRect1, fromView: self.tableView)

        var cellRect2 : CGRect = self.tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![1])
        cellRect2 = self.tableView.superview!.convertRect(cellRect2, fromView: self.tableView)


        if self.tableView.frame.contains(cellRect1) {

            if cell1.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing {
                print("keep playing")
            }else{
                cell1.videoURL = NSURL(string: self.objects[indexPaths![0].row]["storyLink"]!)!
                cell1.displayVideo()
            }


        } else if self.tableView.frame.contains(cellRect2) {

            if cell2.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing {
                print("keep playing")
            } else {
                cell2.videoURL = NSURL(string: self.objects[indexPaths![1].row]["storyLink"]!)!
                cell2.displayVideo()
            }
        }

    } else if indexPaths?.count > 2 {

       let cell1:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![0] as NSIndexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let cell2:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![1] as NSIndexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let cell3:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![2] as NSIndexPath) as! TableViewCell


        var cellRect1 : CGRect = self.tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![0])
        cellRect1 = self.tableView.superview!.convertRect(cellRect1, fromView: self.tableView)

        var cellRect2 : CGRect = self.tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![1])
        cellRect2 = self.tableView.superview!.convertRect(cellRect2, fromView: self.tableView)

        var cellRect3 : CGRect = self.tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths![2])
        cellRect3 = self.tableView.superview!.convertRect(cellRect3, fromView: self.tableView)


        if self.tableView.frame.contains(cellRect1) {

            if cell1.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing {
                print("keep playing")
            }else{
                cell1.videoURL = NSURL(string: self.objects[indexPaths![0].row]["storyLink"]!)!
                cell1.displayVideo()
            }

        } else if self.tableView.frame.contains(cellRect2) {

            if cell2.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing {
                print("keep playing")
            } else {
                cell2.videoURL = NSURL(string: self.objects[indexPaths![1].row]["storyLink"]!)!
                cell2.displayVideo()
            }

        } else if self.tableView.frame.contains(cellRect2) {
            if cell3.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackState.Playing {
                print("keep playing")
            } else {
                cell3.videoURL = NSURL(string: self.objects[indexPaths![2].row]["storyLink"]!)!
                cell3.displayVideo()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works but is not really what I'm looking for.  I really want to pause videos as I scroll and a new cell is visible.

I'm sure that there are much better ways to accomplish this, but as I mentioned before I'm a newby and am piecing this together from things I find online.

Any help is EXTREMELY appreciated.